# in-app-purchase alert in landscape mode on ios7

Tags: in-app-purchase, alert, ios7

I am facing issues when displaying an in-app purchase alert inside my app.
When the user has to enter its App Store's username and password, in landscape mode on the iPhone/iPod Touch (works fine on the iPad), username and password fields get overlapped in iOS 7.

Is this an iOS 7 bug? How can I know if it's been reported to Apple already?

Comment: Well, and your question is? Without any additional information it is not possible to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: I have the same problem. I think we can confirm this is somewhat a iOS7.0 bug.

Comment: I, too, have identified this problem (iphone landscape-only app). I have submitted a bug to Apple. It would be a good idea for others to as well.